# Updating OSX in Mac Mini

Tags: upgrade, macos

I recently purchased a Mac Mini late 2012 Ivy bridge 2.3ghz i7 quad core and upgraded to 16GB memory.  I understand the pre-installed OS is 10.8.1 (12B2080).
I could update to OS 10.10 but I want to ask the question if I need to.
I am a basic user making the switch from Win XP.  My thoughts are, "if it ain't fixed, don't broke it".  I am mostly concerned with updating for security, but dont wany any system conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't support its OSes as long as Microsoft supported XP.

Wise advice would be possibly "Don't jump right now, but don't leave it too long"

It's always wise to wait until applications are updated to support a new OS & initial bugs are ironed out, so waiting for 10.10.1 would be a sensible precaution, but you don't really want to hold off until it's so out of date that if you upgrade nothing you currently own will run.

Answer (score 0):

Some key areas to consider also play into the functionality you wish to utilize across Apple platforms.

OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) implements iCloud Drive which will allow you to share files and resources with your iOS 8 devices and other OS X 10.10 devices.  This functionality alone may be worth the free upgrade alone for some users.

It also implements a new function called Handoff which lets you complete work you may have started on another device.

Messages integrates with your iPhone now as well and allows you to send SMS via your OS X device.

Here is an overview of what's new in 10.10: http://help.apple.com/osx-yosemite/whats-new/

A lot to consider when coming from 10.8.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with 10.8 i would at least recommend to update to 10.8.5 with the [Combo Installer](http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1676/en_US/OSXUpdCombo10.8.5.dmg) and install subsequently the [Security Update 2014-005 Mountain Lion](http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1771/en_US/SecUpd2014-005MtLion.dmg) which both address bug fixes and security flaws.

The same applies for all Apple app updates (Safari, iTunes etc) which are handled by the `App Store.app`.